# Changing an id from an int to an object representation

Tags: java

We did a big code change changing a node id, which used to be represented by an int, to be now represented by a NodeId object.  The challenging task now is to identify all the places that are using object == to change them to .equals().  The same for the != operator.

Is there any script or anything that exists or can be written that can identify the places more accurately than a manual eyeballing?

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe something link Netbeans "Find Usage" can help you. But this will find all usages of the variable, not only '==' and '!='...

Comment: How many files is the usage spread across? Do you use consistent variable names when you use the node id? If it's just a matter of finding where they are (because the usage is completely consistent) then you can use a regex function in Sublime Text and replace all across a specified amount of files/folders.

Comment: Thanks.  The variable names are not the same everywhere.  Many people worked on the project. The number of files modified is about a 1000.

Comment: I would be strongly tempted to change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you are out of luck.  NetBeans does not support "Find Usages" for binary operators, and a quick web search does not reveal any other tools which might.  Ironically, if you wanted to replace `NodeId.equals()` with `==`, "Find Usages" would be the right tool.

Have you considered making `NodeId` immutable and using a Factory Pattern to make every equivalent instance of `NodeId` unique?  Then you would not need to replace `==` and `!=`.  This is also faster than using `equals()`, but makes object creation take longer.  This may seem like an overly complicated solution to a simple problem, but consider the trouble that a single missed `==` or `!=` could be to track down later on.  In contrast, you can probably write the factory code in less time than it will take you to manually search for `==` and `!=` and it should be easy to unit test.

Here is a simple example where the equivalence of different instances of `NodeId` depends on an `int`.  Modify the `HashMap` key to fit your use case.  If you don't need multiple factories, you can use a static factory method with a static map rather than a class.

```
public class NodeId {
    private final int id;

    private NodeId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof NodeId) return id == ((NodeId)obj).id;
        else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 29 * hash + this.id;
        return hash;
    }

    public static class Factory {
        Map<Integer, NodeId> assigned = new HashMap<>();

        public NodeId getInstance(int id) {
            NodeId nodeId = assigned.get(id);
            if (nodeId == null) {
                nodeId = new NodeId(id);
                assigned.put(id, nodeId);
            }
            return nodeId;
        }
    }
}
```

A simple test class demonstrates usage.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeId.Factory factory = new NodeId.Factory();
        NodeId a = factory.getInstance(42);
        NodeId b = factory.getInstance(42);
        NodeId c = factory.getInstance(3);
        System.out.println(a == b); // Should print "true"
        System.out.println(a == c); // Should print "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If we actually serialize the NodeId and deserialize, then there could be an issue there as the NodeId creation did not go through the factory.

Comment: If you were to decide to make `NodeId` serializable, you would always have the option of implementing the `writeObject()`, `readObject()`, and `readObjectNoData()` methods to specialize how `NodeId` serialization is handled.  This does make things more complicated, so you have to weigh the costs and benefits, but it sounds like you've got an awful lot of code to modify (about 1000 files).  Unless you have extensive regression tests, I would recommend the approach that doesn't require you to modify your existing code.